# How I can consult fields when selecting a row in p:dataTable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a form and data table, **my problem is when I select a row in my table, all fields are consulted expect a field because it depends with another field.** I will appreciate if you help me to consult this field.

my form

```
<p:outputLabel for="Portfolio" value="#{msg['Portfolio']}" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="Portfolio" value="#{cashMvtView.beanCashMvt.portfolio}" style="width:120px">
                        <p:ajax listener="#{cashMvtView.onPortfolioChange}" update="Cashaccount" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selectionner un portefeuille" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{cashMvtView.portfolios}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel for="Cashaccount" value="#{msg['Cashaccount']}" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="Cashaccount" value="#{cashMvtView.beanCashMvt.cashAccount}" style="width:120px">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selectionner un compte" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{cashMvtView.cashAccounts}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

cashMvtView.onPortfolioChange:

```
public void onPortfolioChange() {        
    if(beanCashMvt.getPortfolio() !=null && !beanCashMvt.getPortfolio().equals("")){            
        cashAccounts = data.get(beanCashMvt.getPortfolio());            
    }
    else
        cashAccounts = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
```

CashMvtView.java:

```
private Map<String,Map<String,String>> data = new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>();
private String portfolio; 
private String cashAccount;  
private Map<String,String> portfolios;
private Map<String,String> cashAccounts;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    portfolios  = new HashMap<String, String>();
    portfolios.put("Portefeuille1", "Portefeuille1");
    portfolios.put("Portefeuille2", "Portefeuille2");
    portfolios.put("Portefeuille3", "Portefeuille3");

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Portefeuille1_1", "Portefeuille1_1");
    map.put("Portefeuille1_2", "Portefeuille1_2");
    map.put("Portefeuille1_3", "Portefeuille1_3");
    data.put("Portefeuille1", map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Portefeuille2_1", "Portefeuille2_1");
    map.put("Portefeuille2_2", "Portefeuille2_2");
    map.put("Portefeuille2_3", "Portefeuille2_3");
    data.put("Portefeuille2", map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Portefeuille3_1", "Portefeuille3_1");
    map.put("Portefeuille3_2", "Portefeuille3_2");
    map.put("Portefeuille3_3", "Portefeuille3_3");
    data.put("Portefeuille3", map);
}

public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getData() {
    return data;
}

public String getPortfolio() {
    return portfolio;
}

public void setPortfolio(String portfolio) {
    this.portfolio = portfolio;
}

public String getCashAccount() {
    return cashAccount;
}

public void setCashAccount(String cashAccount) {
    this.cashAccount = cashAccount;
}

public Map<String, String> getPortfolios() {
    return portfolios;
}

public Map<String, String> getCashAccounts() {
    return cashAccounts;
}
```

my data table:

```
<p:dataTable var="cashMvt"  value="#{cashMvtView.listeFilteredCashMvt}" 
                                 selectionMode="single" filteredValue="#{cashMvtView.listeFilteredCashMvt}"
                                 selection="#{cashMvtView.selectedCashMvt}" 
                                 rowKey="#{cashMvt.id}"  tableStyle="width:auto"
                                 paginator="true" widgetVar="tabRecherche" id="tabRecherche"
                                 paginatorPosition="bottom"  rows="14"
                                 paginatorTemplate="{Exporters} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} 
                                 {RowsPerPageDropdown} {JumpToPageDropdown} {Controle}" 
                                 >
                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect"  listener="#{cashMvtView.onRowSelect}"  update="form form2" id="ajaxRS" />

                            <p:column style="white-space: nowrap" headerText="#{msg['Portfolio']}" sortBy="#{cashMvt.portfolio}" ><h:outputText value="#{cashMvt.portfolio}" /></p:column>
                            <p:column style="white-space: nowrap" headerText="#{msg['Cashaccount']}" sortBy="#{cashMvt.cashAccount}" ><h:outputText value="#{cashMvt.cashAccount}"/> </p:column>
```

cashMvtView.listeFilteredCashMvt is a list that return what I want to display in my form

this is a screen for my web app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJM8B.png)

As you see, all fields are consulted expect "comptes especes" (cashaccount in my code) 
Note that "portefeuille" in this scrren is portfolio in my code.

Comment: You're updating `Cashaccount` on the select change, have you tryied to update the entire `@form` ?

Comment: I need to update only the cashacount, because it depends with potfolio, any way, I fixed the problem : I added a code in  cashMvtView.onRowSelect, in my data table.

Comment: `public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        beanCashMvt = mapper.map(selectedCashMvt, HcashMvtVO.class)  ;         
//        System.out.println("onRowSelect===================" + beanCashMvt.getCashAccount()); 
        if (beanCashMvt.getPortfolio() != null && !beanCashMvt.getPortfolio().equals("")) {
            cashAccounts = data.get(beanCashMvt.getPortfolio());
        } else {
            cashAccounts = new HashMap<String, String>();
        }
    } 
`

Comment: Perfect! Now, if you have a moment, you could add this as a response to your question so it's easier to find for anyone facing the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem : I added this code in cashMvtView.onRowSelect, in my data table.

```
 public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    beanCashMvt = mapper.map(selectedCashMvt, HcashMvtVO.class)  ;         
    if (beanCashMvt.getPortfolio() != null && !beanCashMvt.getPortfolio().equals("")) {
        cashAccounts = data.get(beanCashMvt.getPortfolio());
    } else {
        cashAccounts = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
}
```